# The geometry nodes are not being shown in the final render, but they appear correctly in the viewport

Tags: cycles-render-engine, geometry-nodes, eevee-render-engine, animation-nodes, procedural

Im trying to make a fireworks render for a project (tutorial by Cartesian Caramel)
This is how they show up in the viewport :
[image]

but while rendering they don't show up at all. I want to have the show up in cycles but Eevee would be fine as well. I've been trying to solve this for a while but I can't find where I went wrong.

The blend file : [image]

EDIT :
I have managed to get the rendered images that I needed. It was much more work but: Duplicating the instance and converting it to a mesh works. You have to do it for each frame but it works.
It's not a solution to the problem though.

Comment: Try moving the camera X location to 200m and try again. - I suspect that the camera is much too close to the origin so can't actually capture the firework images!

Comment: Make sure the geometry nodes modifier is turned on for render